# pip installation throws IOerror - no setup.py

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I'm packaging my project via setup.py of a following structure:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup

def read(fname):
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()

setup(
    name = "blah",
    version = "0.0.1",
    author = "Chuck Norris",
    author_email = "xyz@gmail.com",
    description = ("blah blah blah."),
    license = "BSD",
    keywords = "django",
    url = "http://packages.python.org/blah",
    packages=['blah'],
    long_description=read('README'),
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
        "Topic :: Utilities",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License",
    ],
)
```

My directory structure is

```
folder/
--blah/__init__.py
--blah/other stuff
--readme
--setup.py
```

When installing the .egg with pip, I get error `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-Us23IZ-build/setup.py'`.

When unzipped, egg does not contain setup.py, indeed. I'm not sure whether it should, or not, or is it of any relevance to the error at all.

Thanks.

Comment: Show us, how you build the egg (or other type of package you are building). It shall look somehow like `$ cd folder`, `$ python setup.py build_egg` and finally `$ ls dist`. Alternatively you can try to build pure source package using `$ python setup.py sdist`

Comment: pytpon setup.py bdist_egg

Comment: Hmmm. My `$ python setup.py --help-commands` does not offer such an option. I am using Python 2.7, which one do you use? Anyway, what if you try siply using `sdist` option (assuming, you do have pure python module).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely, you have `setup.py` in wrong directory.

Proper directory structure is:

```
projectroot/
  setup.py
  README
  blah/
    __init__.py
    <whatever other modules your package needs>
```

Packaging (calling the `setup.py` to build an egg or other distribution package) shall be done from projectroot.

After creation of the egg file, you shall visit it (the egg file is zip archive) and check, if `setup.py` is present.

Comment: @ror6ax see my comment at your question above.