# pip installation throws error - no setup.py

Tags: python, pip

I created package on pypi.python.org via setup.py of a following structure:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
name='my_project',
version='1.0.0',
packages=find_packages(),
long_description='My project',
package_data={
    "MyProject.libraries": [
        "darwin/lib.so",
        "linux/lib.so",
        "windows/lib.pyd",
    ],
},
```

)

My directory structure is

```
myproject/
--libraries/
----__init__.py
----darwin/
------lib.so
----linux/
------lib.so
----windows/
------lib.pyd
readme
setup.py 
other files
```

When installing with pip:

```
pip install my_project
```

I get error

```
  Failed building wheel for myproject
  Running setup.py clean for myproject
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-fsZH4w/myproject/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/tmp/pip-build-fsZH4w/myproject/setup.py'
```

But package installed and working fine.

I found similar question [pip installation throws IOerror - no setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27815146/pip-installation-throws-ioerror-no-setup-py) but my setup.py is in root package directory, so I don't think it is the same problem.

Comment: Did you check naming consistency? You have 'my_project', 'MyProject' and 'myproject' at once. I guess it have to be the same all the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's about naming conventions which have following rules

- All lowercase
- Should be unique on pypi
- Underscore-separated or no word separators at all (don’t use hyphens)

Here is the sample structure for python package

```
uniq_package/
  uniq_package/
    __init__.py
  linux/
    lib.so
  darwin/
    lib.so
  windows/
    lib.pyd
  setup.py
```